# Disable https on localhost

Tags: apache, https

I need to automatically redirect any https:// to http:// on my localhost environment.
I tried to use a .htaccess file which I placed on my htdocs/ with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

For some reason this is not working. Any advice?

Comment: What web server software are we talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the rewrite rule is that it will never be reached if apache is not configured properly for SSL. The browser is trying to connect to http://localhost:443 and unless apache or some other service is configured on that port you'll get a timeout.

The best solution would be to create a self-signed certificate for apache running on localhost and create a rule in your web browser to trust the certificate:

Create a self-signed certificate for apache:

http://www.perturb.org/display/entry/754/

Comment: Thanks!
Seems to solve the problem, but I couldn't create a self-signed certificate following your link because I'm currently running it on Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't set a self SSL certificate.
Anyone has a step-by-step guid for Apache 2.2 on Windows?

Comment: This looks like a pretty good guide: http://www.neilstuff.com/apache/apache2-ssl-windows.htm

Comment: I've Apache 2.2 which already comes with OpenSSL support. Do I need to download Hunter's distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Click on Xampp config and add this line to httpd.conf

```
SSLEngine off
```

[image]